# Why tabindex of a HTML element override as -1?

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, tabindex

I have set tab index of a HTML element as '`0`' but while loading in UI it changed to '`-1`' automatically.

The following is my actual logic with Angular4 code,

```
<div *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i = index">
        <h4  id="name" tabindex="0" aria-label="{{employee.name}}">{{employee.name}}</h4>
        <p tabindex="0" aria-label="{{employee.id}}">{{employee.id}}</p>
        <p><a  role="link" target="_blank" href="url" aria-label="Show Details" tabindex="0">Show Details</a></p>
        <button  role="button"  aria-label="Move Next" tabindex="0">Move Next</button>
</div>
```

For every element i added tabindex as '0'

*ngFor is nothing but an iteration loop.

I have 4 objects in the **employees** array.

So it is iterated and loaded in the UI

First 3 occurrences loads as expected wiht tabindex="0" for all the four elements inside the div.

But for the fourth occurrence the tabindex of  and  changed as "-1". So accessibility not working for these 2 elements.

Find the elements loaded in the browser

```
    <div >
    <h4  id="name" tabindex="0" aria-label="Employee1">Employee1</h4>
    <p tabindex="0" aria-label="10001">10001</p>
    <p><a  role="link" target="_blank" href="url" aria-label="Show Details" tabindex="0">Show Details</a></p>
    <button  role="button"  aria-label="Move Next" tabindex="0">Move Next</button>
</div>
<div >
    <h4  id="name" tabindex="0" aria-label="Employee2">Employee2</h4>
    <p tabindex="0" aria-label="10002">10002</p>
    <p><a  role="link" target="_blank" href="url" aria-label="Show Details" tabindex="0">Show Details</a></p>
    <button  role="button"  aria-label="Move Next" tabindex="0">Move Next</button>
</div>
<div >
    <h4  id="name" tabindex="0" aria-label="Employee3">Employee3</h4>
    <p tabindex="0" aria-label="10003">10003</p>
    <p><a  role="link" target="_blank" href="url" aria-label="Show Details" tabindex="0">Show Details</a></p>
    <button  role="button"  aria-label="Move Next" tabindex="0">Move Next</button>
</div>
<div >
    <h4  id="name" tabindex="0" aria-label="Employee4">Employee4</h4>
    <p tabindex="0" aria-label="10004">10004</p>
    <p><a  role="link" target="_blank" href="url" aria-label="Show Details" tabindex="-1">Show Details</a></p>
    <button  role="button"  aria-label="Move Next" tabindex="-1">Move Next</button>
</div>
```

**See the difference in the 4th div tabindex of  and  updated as "-1"**

Everything is the loop remaining are working as expected but why not the last occurrence?

Can anyone clarify me

Comment: What browser are you using? Maybe it's a browser related issue.

Comment: Probably not the cause of the problem but make sure that each element has a different `id` (or remove that attribute if not needed). All your `h4` elements have `id="name"`.

Comment: @Daniel: Checked in browsers like Chrome, FF, Edge. All are having this issue

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz to reproduce? When I copied the code into a stackblitz and ran it, everything had the right tabindex (0)..,

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the issue. See my tests on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmjmhw

Comment: I don't understand why you add `tabindex` to these elements in the first place. Headings such as `h4` normally don't get `tabindex` because they aren't interactive elements; `a` doesn't need it because it is already in the tab order natively. What goal (i.e. what type of interaction or UI) are you trying to achieve?